How to not match (negative match) certain patterns in lookbehind
I'd like to match the word Date only in these strings:

somewords someDate;
 someDate;
someDate(
someDate;

Not in these strings:

 Date(
 Date;
Date;
 Date
someDate
Java.localDate;

I've managed everything except for not match the Date in Java.localDate; with:
(?<=\w)Date(?=;|\()

Please check my Regex101 demo.
Could someone please help with the last step? Thanks!

Wait you want to match " someDate;" but not "someDate"? Based on what?

/(?<=some)Date(?=;|\()/ would work but that's probably not what you want

Your question is vague. You need to state in words, precisely, the rules for determining what is to be matched. For example, you wish to match "Date" in " someDate;" and "someDate;" but not in "Java.localDate;". Does that mean "Date" must be preceded by one or more lowercase letters which are either at the beginning of the string or are preceded by a space?

Since you wish to match a particular string ("Date"), within a string that has certain properties your question is equivalent to determining whether the string itself has those properties. If those certain properties are that "Date" is present and is followed by ";" or "(" at the end of the string and is preceded by one or more lowercase letters that are at the beginning of the string or are preceded by a space, then you may attempt to match (?:^| )[a-z]+Date[;(]$. Demo

When you use regex101.com you enter one string on each line and do not included the single or double quotes that define the string. The g and m flags need to be set to test the regex against multiple strings (one per line). See the link in my comment above.

The regex demo you've given, selected "PCR2 (PHP >= 7.3)" as regex engine, so in that case you could use the \K (i.e., "keep out") feature:
(?<!\.)\b\w+\KDate(?=[;(]) (regex demo)
This rejects inputs where the word ending in "Date" is preceded by a point, like in Java.localDate;. If there are other characters (punctuation?) which also cannot occur right before the word, then list them like this (?<![.,;]).
If you don't have support for \K in your regex engine, then you could use a capture group. You'd match the whole word, but capture group 1 will represent "Date" in the match:
(?<!\.)\b\w+(Date)(?=[;(]) (regex demo)

You could keep out "local" with a negative lookbehind, and start the match with \B which is the opposite of \b to make sure that there is a preceding word character
(?<!\blocal)\BDate(?=[;(])

See a regex demo
